# The entity name must immediately follow the '&' in the entity reference BUT I HAVE PUT &amp;

Tags: xml, xml-parsing

I have this XML Code : and I escaped the `&` character with `&amp;` however, I'm still getting error , but only in this online parser tool:
http://www.xmlvalidation.com
in the Visual Studio Tools for Applications 2.0 program, I'm not getting that error... is this the fault of  the online validation tool or my fault? Is there any other good online validation tool with which I can quickly validate XML Code?? thanks for help...
this is the fault passage: Kurz & knapp,

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<!-- Beseitigen Sie alle Fehler! --> <!--Fehler schon beseitigt!-->

<buchkatalog>
<catalog>

    <!-- Dieses Buch ist zweimal vorhanden -->
    <buch signatur="55.3 Har 1.Ex" signatur2="55.3 Har 2.Ex">
        <autor>
            <vorname>Elliotte Rusty</vorname>
            <nachname>Harold</nachname>
        </autor>
        <autor>
            <vorname>W. Scott</vorname>
            <nachname>Means</nachname>
        </autor>
        <titel >XML in a Nutshell</titel >
        <verlag>O'Reilly</verlag>
        <DatumderAufnahme>20.01.2003</DatumderAufnahme>
        <bemerkung>Kurz &amp; knapp, aber gut</bemerkung>
    </buch>

    <!-- ein älteres Buch -->
    <buch signatur="55.2  Egg">
        <autor>
            <vorname>Bernd</vorname>
            <nachname>Eggink</nachname>
        </autor>
        <titel >Kornshell-Programmierung</titel >
        <untertitel>Eine systematische Einführung</untertitel>
        <verlag>Hanser</verlag>
        <DatumderAufnahme>4.7.1995</DatumderAufnahme>
    </buch>
</catalog>

<catalog2>
    <buch signatur="51.0 Schoe">
        <autor>
            <vorname>Uwe</vorname>
            <nachname>Schöning</nachname>
        </autor>
        <titel >Theoretische Informatik - kurzgefasst</titel >
        <verlag>Spektrum</verlag>
        <DatumderAufnahme>10.8.2002</DatumderAufnahme>
    </buch>
</catalog2>
</buchkatalog>
```

Comment: That validates fine for me.

Answer (score 1):

A Google search on XML Validator lists this validator near the top:

http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_validator.asp

which seems to agree that your XML is valid.

Also, when I removed the leading spaces, even the validator link you provided indicated that your XML was valid. However, it does not seem to refresh very well. I had to close and re-open the site for it to take the new XML. I think it's not very good at taking the version you actually submitted.